# RSAT and double accounts

Tags: active-directory

Since we are looking at migrating our domain admins to use non domain-admin accounts and runas for admin tasks a discussion has begun.

How do others use RSAT with runas? I know you can Shift+RightClick run as other user to launch it with admin rights, but it looses the icon on the taskbar.

The question also has been put, why do Microsoft release the RSAT tools if they recommend admins to run using non-domain accounts.

Edit: Further to this, some of the initial testing with RSAT via the run as other user command hasn't worked out well. Few of the options don't function in the Hyper-V and Failover Cluster Manager.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not aware of any options not functioning correctly when Runas. At my employer, we must login as non-elevated users and elevate from there. I always cringe when I see my coworkers right-click, select Run as administrator, and type their passwords one or more times to get it right.

My solution is to keep open an elevated command prompt, which I keep track of with a `title ********** %USERDOMAIN% **********`. My personal habit is to `start` new command prompts off of it and start elevated processes from there i.e. `dsa.msc`, etc. If I don't know the command line, I usually right-click the shortcut and copy/paste the path into the elevated prompt. Some paths are hard to determine, like those from the Control Panel. Those you can usually determine by running non-elevated and using Task Manager or procexp to find the path.

Pretty much everything works using this method, with the exception of Windows Explorer. My workaround is to launch an elevated notepad instance and use its `File | Open...` dialog as an elevated Explorer window.

Comment: I've since moved back to being a FT Linux admin instead of FT Windows admin so I can't test this method with Hyper-V but it seems like a good solution to cover most of the issues.